# Internal server error because of the mass data?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, apache, server

I have an excel table which has seveval ten thousands of the data.
Then I build a mysql database and make a table which has the same field on the excel table.
But when I use the Phpmyadmin or the PHPExcel way to insert the data into database,for about 5 minutes,It always show up that 500 Internal server error.
What is the reason for this situation?Is it the data which is mass?Or something else.
My server is Apache+PHP 5.4n+mysql 5.5.40
(Of course,I also changed the max_excution_time on the PHP and the memory_limit)

Comment: Check your apache log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your excel in CSV format and read/use [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

I copy/past my own code for example, but adapt him to your needs

```
$dataload = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$filename.'"
                REPLACE
                INTO TABLE '.$this->csvTable.' CHARACTER SET "utf8"
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
                IGNORE 1 LINES
            ';

$result = (bool)$this->db->query($dataload);
```

Where $filename is a local path of your CSV (you can use dirname(**FILE**) for get it )

This SQL command is very quick (just 1 or 2 second for add/update all the CSV)

Read the doc, but of course you need to have an uniq index on your user table for "replace" works. Maybe you don't need replace but just insert so, forgot this line.

Comment: Thks,bro.It works.Can I ask for another question?I will select the mass data  from the database,so what sql can I use that can make it fast like the "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE"?What about the relation query?such two tables or three tables?Thks.

Comment: Please check resolved if it's work for you. For select the data, I use normal SQL queries (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...etc). Ask a new question if you want more advise, I'm not able to help you more